# PHP SoapClient calling Java Web-Service

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap-client

this is first day I'm looking into Web-Services and I'm already stuck.

I got a simple Java-Code:

```
@WebService
public class ProductCatalog {

    public void getCategory(String category) {
       System.out.println(category);
    }
}
```

Then I got the PHP-Code to call this function:

```
try{
$client = new SoapClient("link/to/wsdl");

$category = "music";

$client->getCategory($category);
}
catch(SoapFault $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();  
}
```

The console output is null.

The following

```
public void getProducts() {
    System.out.println("Works");
}
```

with the same PHP-Code works, so the method call itself is working.

As said, it's my first day, so please don't go too hard on me!

edit: here is the WSDL

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://main/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://main/" name="ProductCatalogService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://main/" schemaLocation="http://127.0.0.1:8080/Testmart/ProductCatalogService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getProducts">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getProducts"/>
</message>
<message name="getProductsResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getProductsResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="ProductCatalog">
<operation name="getProducts">
<input wsam:Action="http://main/ProductCatalog/getProductsRequest" message="tns:getProducts"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://main/ProductCatalog/getProductsResponse" message="tns:getProductsResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ProductCatalogPortBinding" type="tns:ProductCatalog">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="getProducts">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="ProductCatalogService">
<port name="ProductCatalogPort" binding="tns:ProductCatalogPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://127.0.0.1:8080/Testmart/ProductCatalogService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
Call the function like this:

```
$response = $client->getCategory(array("arg0"=> $category));
```

I don't know why, but the first parameters of the function is arg0,
if it's not working, check the webservice with programs that can connect to webservice, and than you'll get the name of params.